# Install VMWare Player on Ubuntu 22.04 (kernel 5.17)

Tags: compiling, vmware, linux-headers

I'm running Ubuntu (Mate) 22.04 with a kernel upgraded to 5.17.4 (I have very new hardware).

After downloading and running the .bundle-file from VM-Ware, the **vmmon** and **vmnet** modules failed to install.

The log showed multiple `stdarg.h` and `stddef.h` not found errors. I tried the solution I found [here](https://redtm.com/blog/vmware-workstation-on-kernel-5.16.0-1debian-testing/):

```
sudo CPATH=/usr/src/linux-headers-5.17.4-051704/include/linux vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
```

But I get multiple  `error: expression in static assertion is not constant`.

How will I get VMWare to run?

Answer (score 6):

I have found a [solution here](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/20-04-vmware-workstation-player-fails-to-build-kernel-modules-vmmon-vmnet/21176). It works, but I would rather like not to download and install code from a third party:

Download the [replacement code](https://github.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules/archive/player-16.2.3.tar.gz) for the modules from [mkubecek's Github repo](https://github.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules).

Now execute:

```
  tar -xzf vmware-host-modules-player-16.2.3.tar.gz
  cd vmware-host-modules-player-16.2.3
  tar -cf vmmon.tar vmmon-only
  tar -cf vmnet.tar vmnet-only
  sudo cp -v vmmon.tar vmnet.tar /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/
  sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
```

After this, VMWare Player will start.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 22.04, old hardware.

I have the same problem after upgrading to kernel 5.17.

I have temporarily "solved" it by reverting back to kernel 5.15.