# VMWare Player not starting after 22.04 upgrade - How to fix

Tags: 22.04, vmware

I have this issue.

[Install VMWare Player on Ubuntu 22.04 (kernel 5.17)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1407411/install-vmware-player-on-ubuntu-22-04-kernel-5-17/1407449#1407449)

And I followed the answer provided.  On the last command:

> sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all

It fails with this:

> [AppLoader] GLib does not have GSettings support. Segmentation fault

I find many repeats of this in the VMWare logs if I try to start VMWare Player and it tried to compile the modules into the Kernel:

```
2022-09-24T02:09:02.435Z In(05) host-5139 /tmp/modconfig-1tm6gJ/vmmon-only/./include/vm_asm_x86.h:67:44: error: expression in static assertion is not constant
2022-09-24T02:09:02.435Z In(05) host-5139    67 |    ASSERT_ON_COMPILE(sizeof(Selector) == 2 &&                                \
2022-09-24T02:09:02.435Z In(05) host-5139       |                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2022-09-24T02:09:02.435Z In(05) host-5139    68 |                      ((__builtin_constant_p(expr) && ((expr) >> 16) == 0) || \
2022-09-24T02:09:02.435Z In(05) host-5139       |                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2022-09-24T02:09:02.435Z In(05) host-5139    69 |                       sizeof(expr) <= 2))
2022-09-24T02:09:02.435Z In(05) host-5139       |                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~    
2022-09-24T02:09:02.435Z In(05) host-5139 /tmp/modconfig-1tm6gJ/vmmon-only/./include/vm_assert.h:372:22: note: in definition of macro ‘ASSERT_ON_COMPILE’
2022-09-24T02:09:02.435Z In(05) host-5139   372 |       _Static_assert(e, #e); \
2022-09-24T02:09:02.435Z In(05) host-5139       |                      ^
2022-09-24T02:09:02.435Z In(05) host-5139 /tmp/modconfig-1tm6gJ/vmmon-only/./include/vm_asm_x86.h:263:7: note: in expansion of macro ‘ASSERT_ON_COMPILE_SELECTOR_SIZE’
2022-09-24T02:09:02.435Z In(05) host-5139   263 |       ASSERT_ON_COMPILE_SELECTOR_SIZE(expr);                            \
2022-09-24T02:09:02.435Z In(05) host-5139       |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2022-09-24T02:09:02.435Z In(05) host-5139 /tmp/modconfig-1tm6gJ/vmmon-only/common/task.c:726:7: note: in expansion of macro ‘SET_TR’
2022-09-24T02:09:02.435Z In(05) host-5139   726 |       SET_TR(tr);
2022-09-24T02:09:02.435Z In(05) host-5139       |       ^~~~~~
```

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Great question - I might have the solution you are looking for.
Per this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bYAdPOSxh8c, you should try running these commands in sequence, and it will resolve the issue.

`sudo apt install libaio1`

`sudo apt install build-essential`

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test`

`sudo apt install gcc9`

Rerun the `sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all` command, and enjoy!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I saw your video while researching a solution to my issue, but since my error wasn't the same as yours, I didn't follow it.  Also, I'm running GCC 11, and I'm not getting the directive that I need an earlier GCC version.  So, not sure of the need to roll back 2 versions to fix this.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really across the what the latest glibc versions are. Anyway I hope you can find the solution to your problem (maybe try the other commands?). Have a great day!

Comment: I did try the other commands with the exception of intalling gcc9, but still the same errors.  It does look like compiler errors, and not sure what the overall solution might be other than digging through the sources and attempting to correct it, but then I might be a slave to that code.  Hoping I see a new version iof VMWare Player soon.  .

Comment: This did not work for me.  Anyone have an update?