# Can't run VMWare Player due to Kernel headers

Tags: kernel, kubuntu, 22.04, vmware

I'm on Kubuntu 22.04 with a kernel version of 5.19.0-32-generic (verified with the command `uname -a`)

I have downloaded VMWare Player 17.0.2 and installed it without problems but when I try to run it I got this error :
[Message Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWLEZ.png)

I have already try to add synlinks with :

```
cd /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build/include/linux
sudo ln -s ../generated/utsrelease.h
sudo ln -s ../generated/autoconf.h
sudo ln -s ../generated/uapi/linux/version.h
```

and put the path with `/usr/src/linux-headers-5.19.0-32-generic/include` but it doesn't work and I got this message : [Message Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dAsw.png)

I have already verified that I got the last kernel headers with :

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Finally I tried this command : `sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all` and got this error :

```
[AppLoader] GLib does not have GSettings support.

(process:15928): GLib-CRITICAL **: 22:33:39.910: g_file_test: assertion 'filename != NULL' failed
Failed to setup build environment.
```

Do you have any ideas of how to solve this problem and run VMWare (if possible without recompiling old kernel modules), thanks.

Comment: "Everybody" including me is unable to get that version of VMware player to work with that kernel version.  The usual error is to do with driver signing, needed by UEFI.

If your not using UEFI, this should not apply to you.  If you are, disable and try again.

Although, the usual error we get is when trying to start a VM it says its missing a driver, it also has that must be compiled message.  But in our case, it compiles without error. Then crashes saying drivers are not loaded.

Comment: I found somebody also with a Glib error, their solution may help:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1431926/vmware-player-not-starting-after-22-04-upgrade-how-to-fix